# nalgebra, decomposing homogeneous matrix into operations

Tags: math, rust, linear-algebra, nalgebra

Does nalgebra have a built in method to decompose a 4x4 homogeneous matrix into its rotation, scaling and translation components?

I went through the documentation but I cannot find anything on the topic.

Comment: Does seem like it is not supported: https://github.com/dimforge/nalgebra/issues/760, even in `nalgebra-glm`. If you are open to alternatives, [`glam`](https://crates.io/crates/glam) has [this feature](https://docs.rs/glam/latest/glam/f32/struct.Mat4.html#method.to_scale_rotation_translation).

Comment: It looks like that decomposition (technically called an [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) is [currently unimplemented](https://github.com/dimforge/nalgebra/blob/f5af5dbff2f0b3582e3874cecf1963578ea1f855/src/third_party/alga/alga_transform.rs#L137-L152)